# withColumnRenamed changes the null type of Column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```python
df = df.withColumnRenamed('mail', 'EmailAddress')
```

changes the nulltype i declared as part of schema (declared as false). is there a way to not let this happen?

Nothing in the pyspark documentation really mentions anything.

```python
schema = StructType([StructField("mail", StringType(), False)])
df = spark.read.json(inputPath, schema = schema)
df = df.withColumnRenamed('mail', 'EmailAddress')
df.printSchema()
```

this outputs:

```python
 |-- EmailAddress: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. What version of spark? Can you add the output of `df.printSchema()` *before* the column is renamed? Maybe you have nulls resulting from the `read.json`?

Comment: even if you do not rename the column , the original nullable will be shown as `true` . Please check.

Comment: @pault I'm using spark version 2.4
And yes you are right, the schema before also shows nullable as true.
Does this means the schema is not reflecting correctly OR does the null property never get set?

Comment: Do you have `null`s in json data?

Comment: nope. no nulls.